# C++ Vector sort odd and even stay

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

whats wrong about this code? I want to sort odd numbers but even stay int their places, made function for this but compilator wont pass this

There is error:

> error: reference to non-static member function must be called

and there is a code:

```
public:
std::vector<int> sortArray(std::vector<int> array)
{
   std::vector<int> sortedArray(array);
   std::sort ( sortedArray.begin() , sortedArray.end() , oddSort );
}

bool oddSort ( const int& left , const int& right ){
  if ( left % 2 && right % 2 )
    return left < right;
  else if ( left % 2 )
    return false;
  else if ( right % 2 )
    return true;
  return left < right;
}
```

Comment: `bool oddSort ( const int& left , const int& right )` must be a static member function or namespace scope or global function

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to declare it as member function while it doesn't use member data?

Comment: I sincerely doubt this will do what you want even after making it `static`. For one, you never return anything from your `sortArray ` function. For another, I don't think your assumption in your comparator will prevent movement of even elements like you think it will. If i read your comparator correctly, all the even elements will be stacked at the beginning of the array, the odds at the end.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah, making it static helped with compile and @WhozCraig is right, it wont work the way I thought, I have to rethink this :) Anyway thanks for help!

Comment: There is no way to get the comparison function to "leave odd numbers alone".  I think your instructor is expecting you to create a vector of pointers to the even numbers, then sort that (with a comparison function), and then rearrange the even numbers.  What *I* would do, is create a vector of the even numbers themselves; sort it; and merge it back into the original vector - overwriting even numbers only.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yeah, thats way I done it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danh's comment is right, but this is actually a duplicate question. However, there are no duplicates with accepted answers yet.

So: the problem is that member functions need a `this` pointer, unless they're `static`. And `std::sort` won't give you a `this` pointer, nor do you need one. So making it `static` is the straightforward solution.

Comment: isn't this what I wrote ?

Comment: yeah, O_Z you answered good but MSalters answer is more explanatory :)

Answer (score 2):

`sort` is not a method of the class so it will not have the correct `this` pointer, so calling a member function is a problem.

> When a non-static class member is used in any of the contexts where
>   the this keyword is allowed (non-static member function bodies, member
>   initializer lists, default member initializers), the implicit this->
>   is automatically added before the name, resulting in a member access
>   expression (which, if the member is a virtual member function, results
>   in a virtual function call).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members). There is a difference between types of non-static member function and static member function. And I believe the cpp concept [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) requires the form like the static ones